# Using octave built-in function in C

Tags: c++, c, octave, built-in

I am told to compile this program using C in octave. I have succeeded in compiling a simple C program before using Octave, but for this one, I have tried and I have no idea how to compile it in C even though I have tried to change some of the C++ language into C language.

```
 #include <iostream>

 #include <octave/oct.h>

 int main (void)

 {
 std::cout << "Hello Octave world!\n";

 int n = 2;

 Matrix a_matrix = Matrix (n, n);

 for (octave_idx_type i = 0; i < n; i++)

 for (octave_idx_type j = 0; j < n; j++)

 a_matrix(i,j) = (i + 1) * 10 + (j + 1);

 std::cout << a_matrix;

 return 0;
 }
```

So is there any solution to this problem? 
Thank you very much and sorry for any mistakes in the post that I made since I'm pretty new in using octave and in this forum.

EDIT (After Alter Mann's Answer):

So this is my C program code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
        printf("Hello Octave World!");

    int n=2;
    Matrix a_matrix = Matrix (n, n);

    for (octave_idx_type i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
            for (octave_idx_type j=0; j<n; j++)
            {
                    a_matrix(i,j) = (i+1) * 10 + (j+1);
            }

            printf ("%d", &a_matrix);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But I got this error

> standalone.c: In function ‘main’:
>   standalone.c:8: error: ‘Matrix’ undeclared (first use in this function)
>   standalone.c:8: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
>   standalone.c:8: error: for each function it appears in.)
>   standalone.c:8: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘a_matrix’
>   standalone.c:10: error: ‘octave_idx_type’ undeclared (first use in this  function)
>   standalone.c:10: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘i’
>   standalone.c:10: error: ‘i’ undeclared (first use in this function)
>   standalone.c:12: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘j’
>   standalone.c:12: error: ‘j’ undeclared (first use in this function)
>   standalone.c:14: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘a_matrix’ 
>   standalone.c:17: error: ‘a_matrix’ undeclared (first use in this function)

Comment: Could you provide your final code? Have you used octave in C language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
```

should be

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

and

```
std::cout << a_matrix;
```

should be

```
printf("%d", a_matrix);
```

But `<octave/oct.h>` can not be used in C:

[A.1.1 Getting Started with Oct-Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Getting-Started-with-Oct_002dFiles.html)

> The first critical line is #include  which makes
>   available most of the definitions necessary for a C++ oct-file. Note
>   that octave/oct.h is a C++ header and cannot be directly #include’ed
>   in a C source file, nor any other language.

[Alternative](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/External-Code-Interface.html):

> The interface is centered around supporting the languages C++, C, and
>   Fortran. Octave itself is written in C++ and can call external C++/C
>   code through its native oct-file interface. The C language is also
>   supported through the mex-file interface for compatibility with
>   MATLAB. Fortran code is easiest to reach through the oct-file
>   interface.

Comment: Yeah, I have edited the code just like what you suggested and I got an error as shown on my edited post.

Comment: `Note that octave/oct.h is a C++ header and cannot be directly #include’ed in a C source file, nor any other language.`

Comment: yes I have removed the octave/oct.h just as I posted and I still get an error. Could you please show me an example on how to use the octave function in C source file?

Comment: You still get an error because `Matrix` is an `octave` type, use `C++` or the mex-file interface for compatibility with MATLAB.

Comment: oh I see. So this code can't be compiled using C, is it right?